# How do I correctly set up ffdshow video filter's Logoaway in Shape XY mode?

Tags: ffdshow

I've been trying to configure the Shape XY filter for National Geographic's logo. It would look like this on the video:

[image]

From what I've found regarding this filter's mask coloring, it should look roughly like this:

> [image]

But when I change the mode to Shape XY, it doesn't seem to matter what other settings I change, it just doesn't work.

I tried inverting the mask, using other different images and random masks, and couldn't get it to work. In other modes it works, so it's not like it's completely misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some scaling algorithm missing, and if you load a bitmap image it can only be rendered when the boarders of the ffdshow window are exactly the same size of the bitmap image.

But, downvoting correct answers is pathologic. He already tried a lot of options and could not get it working, I gave the right tip and get downvotes? You are a strange community!

Comment: Please don’t create multiple accounts.

Comment: I am a guest. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Scott not registered on the site. Try posting an answer from private browsing window and you'll see.

Comment: Can you make it work on your computer and post screenshots of what you're describing? There is apparently a language barrier which would not be an obstacle with screenshots of a working solution.

Comment: @Mr.Lolman: So register one of your accounts and merge them!

Answer (score 0):

Final attempt:

1. convert your png to a 32bit bmp.
2. go to ffdshow - logoaway settings, choose ShapeXY, load the bmp, **set width to 73 and height to 105***, left and top to eg. 10
3. start the video and adjust left and top to find the correct position
4. voilà

   - *73/105 is the size of your png.*

Comment: Please ***STOP CREATING NEW ACCOUNTS!!!***

Comment: That doesn't work on my setup, no matter the image format or bitmap image bitness. And I asked you in comments to your previous attempt to post a solution with screenshots because text only doesn't convince me it would actually work. Sorry if this isn't working for you, but then it's better to just leave it to others.

Comment: Why would screenshots convince you? They could be easily faked. Maybe even I'm not real. Nevertheless:
http://abload.de/image.php?img=logoaway0hudj.gif
http://abload.de/image.php?img=logoawy_settingsfcuqd.png

Comment: PS: You are really arrogant - for a guy, who needs help since more than a year and who is not able to find the solution on his own.

Answer (score -2):

width and height settings in ffdshow have to be the same of the bmp-image.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.